# Batch processing for a dictionary of dictionaries Python

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a very large dictionary of the form vf = {key1:{...}, key2:{...}, key3:{...}, ...}, which is stored as an npz file. Trying to load it at once causes a memory error, so I tried to load it in batches but am not sure how to do so efficiently. The code to load it in batches I have so far is as follows, but it is highly inefficient and takes a very long time to load the array. Can anyone explain how to load the array more efficiently?

```
import numpy as np

vf_file_name = 'vf.npz'

chunksize = 100 # chunksize for inner dict
v_t = {} 

with np.load(vf_file_name, allow_pickle=True) as data: 
    v_t_keys = data['v_t'].tolist().keys()
    for outer_key in v_t_keys:
        v_t[outer_key] = {}
        inner_dict = data['v_t'].tolist()[outer_key]
        inner_keys = list(inner_dict.keys())
        total_chunks = len(inner_keys) // chunksize

        for i in range(total_chunks):
            chunk_keys = inner_keys[i*chunksize:(i+1)*chunksize]
            for k in chunk_keys:
                v_t[outer_key][k] = inner_dict[k]
```